# How do we use DevHub when developers should not have accesss to Production data?

Tags: salesforcedx, licenses, dev-hub

We are getting our feet wet with DevHub. It seems that for our developers to be able to use it we need to give them accounts in our Production org. However, our developers are outside contractors, and we cannot give them access to Production data. Can they use Salesforce DX and scratch orgs without having access to Production? Or is there a license that we could give them that lets them use DevHub without getting access to Production data? Or can we use Permission Sets? How is this situation best handled?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm? I don't think you need to add users to prod org but only dev hub.

Comment: The dev hub *is* prod, but you don't have to provide any access to data other than the scratch org objects (as in the link Jayant posted)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single user in Dev hub , assign it only the rights to manage scratch  orgs then manage Dev hub connexion using jwt flow (using scripts can ease the process)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm

For example, in our team, we have 10 developers using scratch orgs using the same Dev hub user.